# Why am I get getting "undefined reference to" error when compiling a c++ program?

Tags: c++, makefile

I just added one function definition to a .h file and its implementation in its corresponding .cpp file. When I compiled it, I got this compiling error:

```
./query.so: undefined reference to `Recognizer::skip_one_char(std::string const&, std::string const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

In Recognizer.h, I added this:

```
bool skip_one_char(const string &content, const string &tag);
```

And in Recognizer.cpp, I added this:

```
bool skip_one_char(const string &content, const string &tag){
     ...
     return false
 }
```

It seems everything is right, but why do I still this error:

```
undefined reference
```

Also, before I added this additional function implementation to it, the package compiles and runs well.

Answer (score 4):

In Recognizer.cpp you've declared a free-standing function named `skip_one_char`:

```
bool skip_one_char(const string &content, const string &tag){
   ...
   return false;
}
```

... I think what you intended to do was create a *method in the Recognizer class* with that name, i.e.:

```
bool Recognizer::skip_one_char(const string &content, const string &tag){
   ...
   return false;
}
```

... at least, that method is what the linker is looking for and can't find.

Comment: Yes, that might be the reason!